# MS Access - For each occurence of a given variable, increase a "count" value by one?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I'm looking for a query that will: read the current value of one row in one column, compare it to the row above it, and sequentially count up if the row above is a match.  Essentially, this sounds like a running tally-up as opposed to a Count(*), almost like the rows should go Count(Variable)-1 on each set of rows until it hits a minimum of zero.  The below example assumes we have a list of daily sales and counts the occurences of a given product ID.  Is this possible?

Select Count(ProductID) AS SalesCount
Unknown Formula as SalesOccurence

Comment: To the people who put this question 'on hold' - I'm struggling to see how the question is particularly bad, and indeed, compared to many Access questions on this site, it's pretty good. Moreover, it received a plausible answer several hours before you decided it wasn't good enough to receive an answer! WTF?

Answer (score 4):

What you describe can sometimes be accomplished in Access SQL using a *self-join* that includes a greater-than or less-than relation between one of the fields. For example, say we have a table named [SalesHistory] with the data

```
ProductID  SalesDate   DailySales
---------  ----------  ----------
001        2013-10-16         225
001        2013-10-17         195
001        2013-10-18         250
002        2013-10-16         350
002        2013-10-17         375
002        2013-10-18         330
```

The query

```sql
SELECT t1.ProductID, t1.SalesDate, t2.ProductID, t2.SalesDate
FROM 
    SalesHistory t1 
    INNER JOIN 
    SalesHistory t2 
        ON t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID 
            AND t1.SalesDate >= t2.SalesDate
ORDER BY t1.ProductID, t1.SalesDate
```

returns the following result

```
t1.ProductID  t1.SalesDate  t2.ProductID  t2.SalesDate
------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
001           2013-10-16    001           2013-10-16  
001           2013-10-17    001           2013-10-17  
001           2013-10-17    001           2013-10-16  
001           2013-10-18    001           2013-10-18  
001           2013-10-18    001           2013-10-17  
001           2013-10-18    001           2013-10-16  
002           2013-10-16    002           2013-10-16  
002           2013-10-17    002           2013-10-17  
002           2013-10-17    002           2013-10-16  
002           2013-10-18    002           2013-10-18  
002           2013-10-18    002           2013-10-17  
002           2013-10-18    002           2013-10-16
```

Notice that for `t1.ProductID='001'` there is one row returned for `t1.SalesDate=#2013-10-16#`, two rows for `t1.SalesDate=#2013-10-17#`, and so on. So, we can just tweak that query to count up the rows that are returned and that will give us the rank for each date by ProductID

```sql
SELECT t1.ProductID, t1.SalesDate, COUNT(*) AS DateRank
FROM 
    SalesHistory t1 
    INNER JOIN 
    SalesHistory t2 
        ON t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID 
            AND t1.SalesDate >= t2.SalesDate
GROUP BY t1.ProductID, t1.SalesDate
```

...which returns:

```
ProductID  SalesDate   DateRank
---------  ----------  --------
001        2013-10-16         1
001        2013-10-17         2
001        2013-10-18         3
002        2013-10-16         1
002        2013-10-17         2
002        2013-10-18         3
```

If we save that query in Access as [SalesDateRanksByProduct] then we can use it in another query to display that DateRank "counter" alongside the original data:

```sql
SELECT 
    SalesHistory.ProductID, 
    SalesHistory.SalesDate, 
    SalesHistory.DailySales, 
    SalesDateRanksByProduct.DateRank
FROM 
    SalesHistory 
    INNER JOIN 
    SalesDateRanksByProduct 
        ON (SalesHistory.SalesDate = SalesDateRanksByProduct.SalesDate) 
            AND (SalesHistory.ProductID = SalesDateRanksByProduct.ProductID)
ORDER BY SalesHistory.ProductID, SalesHistory.SalesDate;
```

...returning:

```
ProductID  SalesDate   DailySales  DateRank
---------  ----------  ----------  --------
001        2013-10-16         225         1
001        2013-10-17         195         2
001        2013-10-18         250         3
002        2013-10-16         350         1
002        2013-10-17         375         2
002        2013-10-18         330         3
```

Comment: Unfortunately my tables cannot be compared on basis of date.  For instance, my tables are only going to have one instance of an OrderNo, rather than multiple instances across multiple days.  Would it be possible to do the inner join while comparing two text-only fields?

Comment: @user2891306 You haven't given us enough detail about your data to say for sure, but generally speaking, yes, one could use a text field in place of the date field that I used in my example. (That is, there's no reason why the field used for the `>=` join condition *must* be a date field.)