# SQL: Output Row Values to Distinct Count for Number of Instances

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to replicate an Access Formula that will output the Columns in Column "Distributions" to include distinct counts leading up to the value in Column "Count."

For example, if I have an order number that recurs in the data sheet for three lines, I would like the output in the "Distributions" column to count 1,2,3 for each line in the sheet.  **If there is one line to the order, I need only an output of 1 in the column, if there are 70 lines, I need an output of 1-70 for every matching Order Number.**

I already have the "Count" column sorted out, but I can't wrap my head around the necessary code to make the output increment up in the "Distributions" column.  The image below details the sort of output I'm looking for with Sample Data.

[image: Count and Distributions Example]

Comment: I've corrected your tags. This is neither MySQL nor Excel, it is Access. If it is related to Excel in some way then you'll need to explain how.

Comment: Does your table have an incrementing AutoNumber field, a date or timestamp field, or some other way to reliably distinguish one row from another? If so, then my recent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19475796/2144390) may be of interest.

Comment: Unfortunately these are derived tables from different data sources, so the tables do not use Autonumber.  Also, the date value is distinct in that the orders are processed daily, so there really isn't a basis of comparison.